# MongoDB query different fields only if they exist in the request

Tags: mongodb, search

How do you query different fields in a collection based on the request?

For example I have a collection called Cars. Its structure below:
{
make: String,
year: Number,
model: Sting
}

If the request looks like this: {make: "Toyota"}, I need to query the "make" property.

If the request looks like this: {year: 2000}, I need to query the "year" property.

If the request looks like this: {make: "Toyota", model: "Camry"}, I need to query both the "make" and "model" properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB uses Javascript Objects for querying the documents. For example:

```
db.collection.find(QueryObject)
```

where **QueryObject** has key and values, in your case it can be **{make: "Toyota"}**. Request that you are receiving is already in Object Notation so if you directly pass it to **collection.find()** method it should work.

However, it is not a safe practise as it allows your client to request any amount of data directly without sanity checks. Unsafe queries can cause numerous problems.

Answer (score 0):

just like it :-

```
  Reserve.find({event_id:events._id,event_id2:events._id2}, function (err, reservations) {
                if (err) return res.status(500).send("There was a problem finding the reservation."); 
    })
```